# moving elements of array in c, is there a better option

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I am reading input from file (line by line) Each line is a state of a game board. Below is example of input:

> (8,7,1,0,0,0,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,s,s,r,r,g,b,r,g,r,r,r,r,b,r,r,s,b,b,b,b,r,s,s,r,b,b,r,s,s,s,r,b,g,b,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,s) 0

I have used `fgets()` and `strtok()` to split the string at `()`,
My problem:

I want the first 6 integers in their individual variables such as:

```
int column = 8
int row = 7
```

so on..

I want to get rid of the last integer at the end of input- 0
and the chars should be stored in an array, because they represent pieces of a board.

Right now, I have an array with all the integers and chars stored together.

I can iterate through my array, and copy the integers to their variables and then chars to a new array.  But that's inefficient.

Is there another way to do it?

I used `fscanf()` but don't know how to split the string using delimiters.

Thanks

Comment: if it's rigid well formed input, use a single scanf with a format specifier for each input and drop the ones you dont want into void

Comment: What do you mean by "inefficient"? Does your target environment have so little resources that you cannot copy 100 bytes or so?

Comment: ex: fscanf("%d,%d,...%c,%c....) %d", &x,&y,etc)

Comment: Do the numbers tell you how many entries there are in the letters-and-commas part of the line, or is the size of the whole line fixed?

Comment: OK, I haven't been writing something serious in C for several years. But just wondering if there is any feature-rich library for text processing? Almost every day someone on SO asks a question about text processing and manipulation in C.

Comment: @ Klas Lindbäck - I m reading 500,000 lines from the files. Since I am using a while loop and for loop for tokenizing, I don't want to make another array and recopy everything.

Answer (score 3):

WELL-FORMED INPUT ONLY

```
if (fscanf(FILE_PTR, "(%d,%d,...,%c,%c,%c,...,%c) %*d", &column, &row, ..., &chars[0], &chars[1], ...) == 60)
```

or something like that

the `%*d` specifier will discard that input (you didn't want the last number)

for the chars, give pointers to their indices for a preallocated array

for the ints, give the variable pointer/ref

Thank you to Jon Leffler for reminding that you should test the output of `*scanf` (number of things read)!

[More information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

**REEDIT** nope, it was right -

> `int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );`
>
> `format`: C string that contains a sequence of characters that control how characters extracted from the stream are treated:
>
> - Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).
> - **Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%): Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.**
> - Format specifiers: A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%) indicates a format specifier, which is used to specify the type and format of the data to be retrieved from the stream and stored into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

Above quote from [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) I am aware of the hostility towards cplusplus.com here but I do not have access to the standard. please feel free to edit if you do

Comment: @Naz: No, scanf will match other characters in the format string (`(` and `,`) against the input and toss them.  If they don't match (if the input is ill-formed) it will stop at that point and return the number of correctly matched and stored things, which can then be caught as an error, allowing you to issue an error message.  You could then throw away the rest of the line with `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` and attempt to read more if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

> I have used `fgets()` and `strtok()` to split the string at "()"

later

> I used `fscanf()` but don't know how to split the string using delimiters.

I guess if `strtok()` worked for parenthesis, it would work for commas too.

Apart from that: you have several possibilities for doing what you want. Without much context provided, I can't really tell you which one you want, but here we go:

1. Grab a pointer to the first non-integer, and use it as if it was a pointer to the first element of another array, containing the integers only. This avoids all copying and/or moving overhead.
2. Use `memcpy()` to copy only the necessary parts of the array to another array. `memcpy()` is generally highly optimized and faster than the naive for-loop-with-assignment approach.

Comment: ok, I will try memcpy() and see.  I wish there was a better option though, I don't want add things to an array and then recopy everything

Answer (score 0):

if you have a `char *` you can think of it as an array or as a string, as the memory layout is the same...

```
char * input = "(8,7,1,0,0,0,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,s,s,r,r,g,b,r,g,r,r,r,r,b,r,r,s,b,b,b,b,r,s,s,r,b,b,r,s,s,s,r,b,g,b,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,s) 0";
size_t len = strlen(input);
int currentIndex = 0;
char * output = calloc(1,len);
for (int i = 0 ; i<len ; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == '(' || input[i] == ')' || input[i] == ','|| input[i] == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    output[currentIndex++] = input[i];
}
assert(strlen(output) == 63); //well formatted?
char a = output[0];
char b = output[1];
char (* board)[60] = malloc(60); //pointer to array or is it a mal-formed string.
memcpy(board, output+2, 60);
char last = output[62];
```

the main thing that I would add, if you want to use it more like a string, then you have to make the array 1 bigger and set `board[60] = \0;`